# error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug

Tags: react-native, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

When I run "react-native run-android" or "npx react-native run-android" or "cd andriod  ./gradlew clean" those commands then the errors show

```
PS D:\work\Myproject-app> npx react-native run-android
```

```
    info Starting JS server...
    Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status                                 for details

    > Configure project :app
    Reading env from: .env

    FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

    1: Task failed with an exception.
    -----------
    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'security''

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get         more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    ==============================================================================

    2: Task failed with an exception.
    -----------
    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    > compileSdkVersion is not specified.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get         more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    ==============================================================================

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 19s
    error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
    Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
    set up your Android development environment:
    https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
    error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I tried also to use the latest version of Gradle!

OS Windows 10
Node: 14.2.0
Java: java version "1.8.0_251"
      Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
      Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
Gradle version: 5.1.1

JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME, and path added to the environment

Comment: The error log says `compileSdkVersion is not specified`. check if you can add a `compileSdkVersion` in android/build.gradle

Comment: Thanks @B.Mohammad for your comment :)
**here is some code of my android/build.gradle:**


`buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        firebaseVersion = "16.0.1"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.0.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    }
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but....

I ran into this problem today. My situation was that the project worked fine on a mac. However, I needed to get it running on a windows system. Within my android\app\build.gradle file, I setup a getPassword method that would make it easy for me to sign my apk's. Within the getPassword method I had this call:

```
commandLine 'security', '-q', 'find-generic-password', '-a', currentUser, '-s', keyChain, '-w'
```

I commented out all of the references to the getPassword method and it started working without a problem.

The root of the problem is that the "security" commandline tool that mac uses isn't available on windows. Since I'm now needing to use a windows box as well, I've configured the passwords within an external credentials file.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same question, but the first answer is too simple. I don't know how to add a getPassword method and where to add.

However, the first answer inspired me. ‘My situation was that the project worked fine on a mac. However, I needed to get it running on a windows system. ’

we should shift right of CLI commands on Windows 10. type 'cmd' to use the command line tool on by right click, choose administrator mode.
and try 'yarn react-native run-android' or 'npx react-native run-android' again.

yarn will automatically downloads proper vision of gradle which needs. if you see these changes, let's rock.